# How to filter certain rows based on the preceding row's value using dplyr?

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataframe like this:

```
df1 <- data.frame(
  Group = c('A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'Total: CD', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'Total: FG', 'H'),
  Value1 = c(12, 88, 10, 90, 100, 8, 4, 11, 15, 77)
)
```

I would like to filter out any rows that come after a row containing the word `Total` with the result looking like this:

```
df_desired <- data.frame(
  Group = c('A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'Total: CD', 'F', 'G', 'Total: FG'),
  Value1 = c(12, 88, 10, 90, 100, 4, 11, 15)
)
```

How would I achieve this in R, ideally using the `dplyr` package?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `lag` in `dplyr` -

```
library(dplyr)

df1 %>% filter(!lag(grepl('Total', Group), default = FALSE))

#      Group Value1
#1         A     12
#2         B     88
#3         C     10
#4         D     90
#5 Total: CD    100
#6         F      4
#7         G     11
#8 Total: FG     15
```

`grepl` returns `TRUE` where `'Total'` is found and `lag` would lag the result by 1 step so that the next row after `'Total'` is removed.

Comment: could you explain your code.Thanks

Comment: Added some explanation to the code @user10974052

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this:

```r
library(tidyverse)

df1[-c(which(str_detect(df1$Group, 'Total')) + 1), ]
#>       Group Value1
#> 1         A     12
#> 2         B     88
#> 3         C     10
#> 4         D     90
#> 5 Total: CD    100
#> 7         F      4
#> 8         G     11
#> 9 Total: FG     15
```

<sup>Created on 2021-11-30 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>